# How do I perform this search query in eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to perform a search query with particular tag names in bookmarks for a particular user with this query in eloquent:

> SELECT * FROM `bookmarks_tags` WHERE tag_id in (SELECT id FROM `tags`
>   WHERE name in ('new','please','work')) and bookmark_id in (SELECT id
>   from bookmarks where userid = 1)

I have the following models setup with relationships:

**Tag model**

```
class Tag extends Eloquent
{

   public function bookmarks()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('Bookmark','bookmarks_tags');
    }
}
```

**Bookmark model:**

```
class Bookmark extends Eloquent {

    .....
     public function owner()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('User','id');
    }
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag','bookmarks_tags','bookmark_id','tag_id');
    }


}
```

**And lastly the user model:**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    .....

    public function bookmarks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Bookmark','userid');
    }

}
```

**Here is my db schema:**

[image: DB Schema]

I know that I can get bookmarks and tag id with following:

```
$bookmarkIDs = Auth::user()->bookmarks()->get('id');
 $tagsID = Tag::whereIn('name', $tags)->get('id');
```

But I can't figure how to perform this query for bookmarks_tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your requirements right but this will get you the bookmarks that belong to a user with the specific tags assigned:

```
$tags = ['new', 'please', 'work'];
$bookmarks = Bookmark::whereHas('owner', function($q){
    $q->where('users.id', 1);
})->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags){
    $q->whereIn('name', $tags);
})->get();
```

---

Or alternatively (and actually a bit simpler)

```
$bookmarks = Bookmark::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags){
    $q->whereIn('name', $tags);
})->where('userid', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Hello, I accidentally removed the owner() relationship from the Bookmark model. Can you please take a look again?

Comment: Now you put it in the Tag model. But anyways, if the relationship is called `owner` instead of `user` just use `whereHas('owner', ...`. I edited my answer

Comment: This is the query I get when I run your code: SELECT * FROM `bookmarks` WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE `bookmarks`.`id` = `users`.`id` and `id` = '1') >= 1 and (SELECT count(*) FROM `tags` inner join `bookmarks_tags` on `tags`.`id` = `bookmarks_tags`.`tag_id` WHERE `bookmarks_tags`.`bookmark_id` = `bookmarks`.`id` and `name` in ('new', 'please', 'work')) >= 1

Comment: Which returns no result

Comment: And are you sure that this isn't the expected result? I mean should there be matching bookmarks?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by using: $bookmarks = Bookmark::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tags) {
            $query->whereIn('name', $tags);

        })->where('userid','=',1)->get();

Comment: Ah of course. It should have been `users.id` (obviously `userid` works as well)